# SQLalchemy Integer TypeDecorator for Python IntFlag: filter multiple entries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to use the Python data type `IntFlag` in the application. Only the type `Integer` is available in the database table. To ensure the data exchange between application and DB, I use the Integer **TypeDecorator** from SQLalchemy.

The database already exists and uses MariaDB. Further down *sqlite* is used to make the example easier to follow.

```
from enum import IntFlag, auto
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import create_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class IntegerIntFlag(sa.types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = sa.Integer

    def __init__(self, intflagtype, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._intflagtype = intflagtype

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return value.value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return self._intflagtype(value)


class Dog(IntFlag):
    Puppy = auto()
    Medium = auto()
    Old = auto()
    TailWag = auto()
    Bark = auto()
    Run = auto()
    Hunt = auto()
    Sleep = auto()
    CatsLike = auto()
    CatsDislike = auto()

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
Base = declarative_base()


class DogTbl(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dogs'

    Id = sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = sa.Column('name', sa.String)
    State = sa.Column('state', IntegerIntFlag(Dog))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add(DogTbl(Name='dogA', State=Dog.Puppy))
session.add(DogTbl(Name='dogB', State=Dog.Medium))
session.add(DogTbl(Name='dogC', State=Dog.Old))
session.commit()
engine.execute(sa.text('insert into dogs values(4, "dogD", 4+16+512);'))

for dog in session.query(DogTbl):
    print(dog.Name, ':', dog.State, '(', dog.State.value, ')')
```

The printing result should look like this:

```
dogA : Dog.Puppy ( 1 )
dogB : Dog.Medium ( 2 )
dogC : Dog.Old ( 4 )
dogD : Dog.CatsDislike|Bark|Old ( 532 )
```

The column `state` of type Integer in the table `dogs` returns the Python data type **IntFlag** correctly.

Filtering for entries that have only 1 status entry is easy:

```
qry = session.query(DogTbl).filter(DogTbl.State == Dog.Puppy).first()
```

But how do I filter for old dogs that also bark?

This is of course only an example. The IntFlag class `Dog` can be extended at will.

I fail at the question how *several* entries of `Dog` apply to the table for filtering. - Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I filter for old dogs that also bark?

[SQLalchemy tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html): see for `Operators.op()`

```
for dog in session.query(DogTbl).\
    filter(
        and_(DogTbl.State.op('&')(Dog.Old),
             DogTbl.State.op('&')(Dog.Bark))).\
        order_by(DogTbl.Name).all():
    print(dog.Name, dog.State)
```

That's half the solution already. I am still interested in using [SQLalchemy automap_base](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html) for my existing MariaDB schema.